# Is Otis in the Bumblebee (Transformers) movie Charlie’s half-brother, adopted brother, or step-brother?

Tags: transformers, bumblebee-2018

Is Otis the son of Ron and a deceased first wife of his?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39088504-transformers-bumblebee), [Ron](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Ron_(BB)) is Otis and Charlie's **step**father.

> Her mother, Sally, was washing dishes, and **her stepfather, Ron, was drying**. Sally was a nurse and was wearing scrubs. Sally and Ron giggled about something, and then they kissed.
>
> ...
>
> “Ah, Otis-san!” Ron said.
>
> “Hiiiii -yah!” Otis said again. His hands launched out and chopped at
> the air **in front of his stepfather.**

[Sally](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sally_Watson) appears to be their their shared biological mother (noting that Charlie repeatedly calls out Ron as her stepfather, but only ever refers to Otis as her brother.

Their shared [biological father](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Charlie%27s_Dad) died quite recently of a heart attack, which is a point of contention with her mother.